# Monospace fonts pixelated in Chrome but not in Firefox for Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I find that the monospaced font in Chrome is pixelated while in Firefox it is fine.

A screenshot from Chrome:
[image]

A same screenshot from Firefox:
[image]

One workaround to fix the pixelation in Chrome is to zoom in/out the page. But this is not right as there should be no pixelation even in normal size.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem since yesterday, after updating to Ubuntu 21.04. All fine in FF, just in Chrome  blurry text. Did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Font visualization problems can be due to different reasons, try one of these:

1. Reset DPI Scaling to 100%
2. Disable Hardware Acceleration Feature in Google Chrome.
3. Right-click on Google Chrome's shortcut and select Properties. Add this entry at the end of the string present in Target text box (leave a blank space before it):

/high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1

4. Restore Classic UI and Theme in Chrome.

Comment: 1. How to reset DPI scaling to 100%?

2. hardware accelration already disabled
3. I am on Ubuntu 18.04, there is no shortcut and properties.
4. Restoring classic UI theme does not help

Comment: Sorry, While writing I forgot it was Ubuntu... I think rescaling to 100%  in Ubuntu should be something like this:    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0

Comment: sadly it still does not work. I tried to paste those into terminal and restarting google chrome. Really not sure why this problem happening. My brother tried to open the same website in Manjaro Linux's Chrome and he does not encounter this poor text rendering. I guess I have to be content with zooming in/out for now.